# javascript equivalent of anchor href

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say my webpage is `http://localhost/myApp/route/index.html`

if I click on:

```
  <li><a href="#secondpage">go to second page</a></li>
```

It will change the route to `http://localhost/myApp/route/index.html#/secondpage` without reloading.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing but with just onclick and javascript instead of anchor tag. Because I need to do something first before I let angular router change to another template.

```
  <li><a onClick="myFunction()">Payroll Run History</a></li>

  myFunction(){
      [... do stuff ...]
      //change to http://localhost/myApp/route/index.html#/secondpage   without reloading page
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set the anchor property:

```
location.hash = "#/secondpage";
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't use `onclick` attribute, browsers and pop-up blockers don't like it. Give an ID to your element and create an event listener in JavaScript.

```js
document.getElementById('my_link').addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Prevent defualt action of event:
  event.preventDefault();

  // Do your extra stuff here...
 
  location.hash = event.target.getAttribute('href').substr(1);
});
```

```html
<a href="#/secondpage" id="my_link">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to navigate to a second page instead of a section of a page..you can use window.location

here is an example

```js
document.getElementById('click').onclick=function(){
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML='I just append this div before changing my location';
document.body.appendChild(div);
window.location='http://www.google.com';
}
```

```css
#click:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<li id='click'>Click here</li>
```

You will notice I added a div to the body tag and then change my location....

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.hash = "secondpage";
```

It will set the `#secondpage` in the URL and will scroll to that ID.